# F# casting obj[,] to float[,]

Tags: casting, f#

I have an `obj[,]` whose components are all `float`s. I want to convert it to a `float[,]`. I tried many permutations of `box`, `unbox`, `Array2D.map float`, `Array2D.copy`, `System.Convert.ChangeType`, etc and none seem to work. How to proceed?

Comment: Show us some code you tried and describe how exactly it is not working. Are there compiler errors, runtime exceptions, unexpected output, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work just fine for me:

```
let boxedArray = Array2D.init 2 2 (fun x y -> box (float (x + y)))
let unboxedArray = boxedArray |> Array2D.map unbox<float>

printfn "%A" (boxedArray.GetType())  // System.Object[,]
printfn "%A" (unboxedArray.GetType())  // System.Double[,]
```

Comment: Got it. I was trying to do `boxedArray |> unbox |> Array2D.map float` and got a runtime `System.InvalidCastException`